# Difference between Welsh rabbit and beer cheese dip

Tags: sauce, cheese, beer

When I have looked at recipes for Welsh rabbit (rarebit), and beer cheese dip / soup, they seem very similar. Does one make a decent substitute for the other?

Answer (score 2):

The similarities…
Fat, flour, cheese, milk

The differences…
Welsh Rarebit - English mustard, Worcestershire sauce
Beer cheese dip - garlic, paprika, dijon mustard, beer [optional in rarebit]

You might swap one for the other, but warn your diners first which they're getting.
If I got garlic in Welsh rarebit I'd probably not eat it, wondering what the heck was wrong with it. if I knew it was meant to be there beforehand, I probably would.

Similar could be said for the Dijon [too vinegary] & paprika [odd colour even before tasting].

I'd eat either & probably enjoy it, so long as I knew what I was getting before I tasted it; otherwise you get that odd mental trip-up like when you think you've been served tea but it's actually coffee. It's revolting until you realise, then it's fine.

BTW, rarebit works really well for Philly cheesesteak ;)